# ToogleMenuFlyout and MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle Set Width - Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: xaml, menu, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I need the items in a `ToogleMenuFlyout` occupy the full `width` of the screen.
But I'm not solve the problem.

I'm trying to put the `width` of my Grid (Grid Main page) but I do not get to do in code-behind.

I am applying a style to `MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle` but also not to give.

my code is:

```
AppBarButton x:Name="FiltersPhone" Icon="Filter" Label="Names">
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                     <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem x:Name="FlyoutItemDate" Text="Today" Tag="Date"
                                           IsChecked="True/>

                </MenuFlyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following should help [**Updated to support landscape**]:

Note that: this is still not a perfect solution to meet all your requirement. I am just trying to let you understand the MenuFlyoutPresenter's Maxwidth and the ToggleMenuFlyoutItem's width properties are the key to impelement what you want.

1. Set x:Name = "rootGrid" to page's root grid
2. In code-behind, implement the following:

   ```
   public Page2()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       this.Loaded += Page2_Loaded;
   }

   private void Page2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       FlyoutItemDate.Width = rootGrid.ActualWidth;
       DisplayInformation di = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
       di.OrientationChanged += Di_OrientationChanged;
   }

   private void Di_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
   {
       if (sender.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait)
       {
           FlyoutItemDate.Width = rootGrid.ActualWidth;
       }
       else if(sender.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Landscape)
       {
           FlyoutItemDate.Width = rootGrid.ActualHeight;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Increase maxwidth of MenuFlyoutPresenter to larger one(like 1000)

   ```
    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
         <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1000"/>
    </Style>
   ```

Here is the result and I make the background to red to make it clear:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, but not work for landscape mode. Only portrait is OK.
I dont know what I do more :(

Comment: updated my answer. in landscape mode set the grid's height to item's width. And set the Maxwidth property of MenuFlyoutPresenter to a larger value.

Comment: Hi, in mode Portrait is perfect!
But in landscape mode not occuped width of screen. Strange :(