# Menu Flyout XAML - C# - Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: xaml, menu, windows-10, appbar, windows-10-mobile

I need my ToggleMenuFlyout occupy the full screen (on my mobile) but I am not able to.

Someone can help me?

My code:

```
AppBarButton x: Name = "FiltersPhone" Icon = "Filter" label = "Names">
                 <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                      <MenuFlyout>
                     <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                         <Style TargetType = "MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                             <Setter Property = "Background" Value = "Transparent" />
                             <Setter Property = "BorderThickness" Value = "0" />
                             <Setter Property = "Margin" Value = "0,4,0,0" />
                         </ Style>
                     </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                     <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem x: Name = "FlyoutItemDate" Text = "Today" tag = "Date"
                                            IsChecked = "True />

                 </ MenuFlyout>
                 </AppBarButton.Flyout>
             </ AppBarButton>
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems a duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948697/tooglemenuflyout-and-menuflyoutpresenterstyle-set-width-windows-10-mobile/32961410#32961410 . Do you want full width of screen or full screen? If it is full width, check my answer in that question. If it's full screen, take @Stanley1 's advice.

Comment: I need toggle menu flyout occuped full width of screen

Comment: Then check my answer in your another question. I've added a screenshot for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton.Flyout >
                <MenuFlyout Placement="Full"></MenuFlyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
```

Best of luck !

Comment: Hi, the problem is the same. Toggle menu flyout not occuped full width of screen.

when I put this, have a small margin on left and right, and the flyout is center.

:(

Comment: That's how flyouts works .. maybe you should implement a popup instead.

Comment: the strange thing is that in Portrait mode is all perfect. But the Landscape is wrong!