# Decrease the size of the Menu Flyout in windows Universal App for Mobile?

Tags: wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am working on windows Universal app(Windows 10) in Mobile.I have query in Menu Flyout.The Menu Flyout's Default  Width remaining same which is not decreased after this code :

```
<AppBarButton Icon="OpenWith" Label="More.." Width="55">
                    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-31,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE45427" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="70" />
                                </Style>
                            </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Logout" FontSize="13" Padding="8,8,0,8"   Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Sales" FontSize="13" Padding="8,8,0,8"  Click="appbarsales_Click" />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
                </AppBarButton>
```

Image:

[image: See the Image of Menu Flyout]

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948697/tooglemenuflyout-and-menuflyoutpresenterstyle-set-width-windows-10-mobile) ?

Comment: @AlexejSommer: Yes. I tried this thing also  but I want to Decrease my menu Flyout width only.I can easily increase the width  but i don't have idea how to decrease the width so kindly suggest a better way if you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar x:Name="applicationbar">
         <AppBarButton Icon="OpenWith" Label="More.."  x:Name="more_item">
                    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-31,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE45427" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="70"/>

                                </Style>
                            </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Logout" FontSize="13" Padding="8,8,0,8"   Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" >

                            </MenuFlyoutItem>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Sales" FontSize="13" Padding="8,8,0,8"  Click="appbarsales_Click" />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
                </AppBarButton>
            </StackPanel>

        </AppBar>
```

Use a **MaxWidth** property to decrease the default size of the Menu Flyout